# How to display multiple handles in jQuery slider using range?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I am using jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery UI 1.9.1.  This is my first try using the slider.

I am trying to get four sliders working on the same page. The first handle shows up just fine but I can't get the second handle to show up.

You can see the full file here http://dev.iqcatalogs.com/avcat/myiq/test-16.cfm

What am I doing wrong?

```
<style>
#SliderWrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.Slider {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 25px;
    float: left;
} 
.Label {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
} 
</style>    

<div id="SliderWrapper">
<div class='Label'></div>
<div class="Slider" data-min='20' data-max='30'></div>
<div class='Label'></div>
<div class="Slider" data-min='30' data-max='40'></div>
<div class='Label'></div>
<div class="Slider" data-min='50' data-max='70'></div>
<div class='Label'></div>
<div class="Slider" data-min='80' data-max='100'></div>
</div>

<script>

$(".Slider").slider().each(function() {

    // SET VARS
    var $this = $(this),
        RangeLow = $this.data("min"),
        RangeHigh = $this.data("max"),
        ValueMin = RangeLow * .75, 
        ValueMax = RangeHigh * 1.25,
        Message = 'from' + ValueMin + ' to ' + ValueMax;

    $this.prev('div').text(Message);

    $this.slider({
        range: true,
        min: ValueMin,
        max: ValueMax,
        values: [RangeLow, RangeHigh],
        orientation: "horizontal"
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "first handle is showing up"?  What do you mean by "handle"?  When I visit your page I see all four sliders appear.

Comment: I believe he'd like each slider to have two handles to define minimum and maximum values in a range.

Comment: It is a range slider. It should have TWO handles, one for the miniumum value and one for the maxium value.  http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Comment: Thanks ajm, Evik - I have added a solution with a JSFiddle for your perusal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the `.slider()` from your `.each()` function.

Ie:
`$(".Slider").slider().each(function() {`

Becomes
`$(".Slider").each(function() {`

EDIT: [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3AdHe/)

The reason your initial code did not work was because you were calling `slider()` before `each()`.  Calling `slider()` on your class added a default slider (single-handle) to your class and then iterated over the slider elements.  This results in your `each()` block attempting to call a double-handle slider on the slider element, not your initially targeted class.

Comment: You are totally correct. That fixed my problem immediately. I can award your bounty in 17 hours from now. Don't hesitate to remind me. Also, if you think this was a good question, don't hesitate to vote it up. :)

Comment: Sure... I will add a more in-depth answer to my question first.